# What is the refresh rate of a manifest file?

Tags: html, css, manifest

I have a really simple manifest file for caching my entire App. It works pretty well, even when offline.

But, after a long time without using it, and I go and open it again, the App starts downloading EVERYTHING, even when the cache file is the SAME as before!

So, does it have any way to block the automatic update of the browser? I mean, I only want it to download the files again **when my manifest file is modified**.

Thanks!

Comment: according to this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/#toc-updating-cache it looks like it is already suppose to do what you you want it to. Since you state 'after a long time', it may be possible that you/or the browser cleared the cache between that time frame.

Comment: @kennypu yeah, I don't know if the browser behavior is different than what html5rocks.com says. One thing that I've discovered: if I restart my webserver, the manifest is treated as "new" for the browser. Weird, huh? I don't see any special headers being passed for the file.